# Couldn't connect to X server in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am working on to build an app in kivy. I am running kivy app inside docker container of ubuntu 20.04 but it is giving error **Couldn't connect to X server**

Below are the logs

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-08-08_46.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (default, Aug  8 2020, 11:45:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/local/bin/python3.7"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: x11(['window_egl_rpi', 'window_sdl2'] ignored)
Couldn't connect to X server
```

**Not sure how to solve this issue.**

I also ran the kivy setup outside of docker env, which is mac os and it is working.

Below are the logs

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/tajinderpalsingh/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-08-09_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Users/tajinderpalsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Users/tajinderpalsingh/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Pygame has been deprecated and will be removed after 1.11.0: Call to deprecated function __init__ in /Users/tajinderpalsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py line 42.Called from /Users/tajinderpalsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py line 71 by core_select_lib().
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-12.4.7'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel HD Graphics 4000 OpenGL Engine'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Pygame has been deprecated and will be removed after 1.11.0: Call to deprecated function __init__ in /Users/tajinderpalsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pygame.py line 36.Called from /Users/tajinderpalsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/label.py line 349 by _create_label().
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

I am able to build apk via buildozer in docker env but it is crashing while opening in android phone. I guess this is due to above mentioned issue(Couldn't connect to X server).

Got stuck on this for quite sometime now and didn't find any workaround.

Comment: The android issue is probably entirely unrelated to the desktop one. Android doesn't even use X. [Debug it](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) if you want to find out more, but that's a different question.

Comment: On the desktop, can you give more information about how you installed kivy, and what is the host OS for the docker container?

Comment: This is probably happening because the container doesn't have X11 installed on it. That'd also be why it runs perfectly outside the container. I don't know why it isn't running on the android phone though.

Comment: For Debugging the apk i have connected my phone to laptop after enabling usb debugging under developer options. After this i go to the docker env and ran the following command ```buildozer android logcat```

Comment: Following are the logs ```#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Run '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices'
# Cwd None
List of devices attached
```

Comment: I installed kivy 1.11.1 via pip on docker with host os ubuntu 20.04. Python version is 3.7.6